# String replace function not replacing characters correctly - Java

Tags: java, replace, character

I am trying to replace a specific character '8' with a '2' in a string. I think I have everything set up correctly and when I look online for examples, this looks like it should. When I print the string though, it is just as I entered it. To run it, test it with "80802" or some similar input. Thanks!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class PhoneNumber {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String number = null;

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Prompt the user for a telephone number
        System.out.print("Enter your telephone number: ");

        // Input the user's name
        number = scan.nextLine();

        // Replace the relevant letters with numbers
        number.replace('8', '2');

        System.out.println("Your number is: " + number );

    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A common mistake... You want:

```
    number = number.replace('8', '2');
```

[String.replace()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28char,%20char%29) doesn't change the String, because [Strings](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) are immutable (they can not be changed). Instead, such methods *return* a new String with the calculated value.

Comment: Ahh. So that simply creates a new string with 8's as 2's and reassigns it to number?

Comment: Works perfectly and makes great sense! Thank you so much and I am pleased to know it is a common mistake =x

Answer (score 2):

`number.replace()` returns a new string.  It does not change `number'.

Answer (score 0):

number.replace('8','2'); returns the correct string it does not modify number.  To get your desired functionality you must type 
number = number.replace('8','2');

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String number = null;

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    // Prompt the user for a telephone number
    System.out.print("Enter your telephone number: ");

    // Input the user's name
    number = scan.nextLine();

    // Replace the relevant letters with numbers
    number = number.replace('8', '2');

    System.out.println("Your number is: " + number );

}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Another user answered first but it does really help! Thank you!